# 栄光の Glorious as a username does it make sense?

Tags: adjectives

I want to set my username as glorious and google translate gave me 栄光の and I want to ask if it will make sense to write it alone or does it have to be written with a sentence

Comment: No, it wont really make sense like this.

Answer (score 2):

It does have to be written with a sentence. The third character, の, is a Japanese particle which is similar in purpose to the English preposition "of". 栄光の comes off as **"of glory"** rather than "glorious". (You can read about the grammar [here](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/na-adjectives-no-adjectives/).) 栄光 without の means "glory", which would usually look more natural as a username.